# python factory functions compared to class

Tags: python, function

Simple example of a nested function:

```
def maker(N):
    def action(X):
        return X * N
    return action
```

Do factory functions have advantages over creating a class? Performance, memory, clean up?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What I like most about nested functions is that it is less verbose than classes. The equivalent class definition to your maker function is:

```
class clsmaker(object):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
    def __call__(self, X):
        return X * self.N
```

That doesn't seem so bad until you start adding more arguments to the constructor. Then doing it the class way takes an extra line for each argument, while the function just gets the extra args.

It turns out that there is a speed advantage to the nested functions as well:

```
>>> T1 = timeit.Timer('maker(3)(4)', 'from __main__ import maker')
>>> T1.timeit()
1.2818338871002197
>>> T2 = timeit.Timer('clsmaker(3)(4)', 'from __main__ import clsmaker')
>>> T2.timeit()
2.2137160301208496
```

This may be due to there being fewer opcodes involved in the nested functions version:

```
>>> dis(clsmaker.__call__)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (X)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                0 (N)
              9 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             10 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> act = maker(3)
>>> dis(act)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (X)
              3 LOAD_DEREF               0 (N)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: that's a significant time difference..interesting results

Comment: Is there a way to unit test nested functions?

Answer (score 20):

Comparing a function factory to a class is comparing apples and oranges.  Use a class if you have a cohesive collection of data and functions, together called an object.  Use a function factory if you need a function, and want to parameterize its creation.

Your choice of the two techniques should depend on the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 6):

Nesting functions allows one to create custom functions on the fly.

Have a look at e.g. [decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). The resulting functions depend on variables that are bound at  creation time and do not need to be changed afterwards. So using a class for this purpose would make *less* sense.