# How to deal with large csv file in python?

Tags: python, function, csv

I have CSV file that contains a data of 40k rows.

My each function open csv file and works with it and then close it.
Is there a way that I can open the file once and then close it and I can work with it whenever I want? I tried to put each field in a separate list and work whit it whenever I call it or in dictionary but both methods works good  up to 1k row if more then it takes long time to processes it, I found a way to speed up by filtering them, but not sure how to apply it.

sample of my codes.

```
files=open("myfile.csv","r")


def spec_total():
    total = 0.0
    files.readline() # skip first row
    for line in files:
        field=line.strip().split(",")  #make Into fields
        tall=float(field[0])      
            if tall >= 9.956:
        total +=tall
    print("The sum is: %0.5f" % (total))

spec_total()
files.close()
```

other function

```
files=open("3124749c.csv","r")
def code():
    match= 0
    files.readline() # skip first row
    for row in files:
        field=row.strip().split(",") #make Into fields
        code=(field[4])
        import re
        if re.search(r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+', code) is None:
            match += 1
    print("The answer that do not match code is :",match)

code()

files.close()
```

and there is plenty more functions that opens each time the csv file and split them into field in order to recognise which field I am referring to.

Comment: "Have to"? Why? Rephrase your question in a "I want to achieve XY, and I have done this so far", and you'll get better luck

Comment: Look to use the standard library ``csv`` and it would seem to make sense to call ``total(field[0])`` and not have it access a global piece of data.

Comment: @Dragets: It is not at all clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Can you rephrase, please?

Comment: I rewrote the question hopefully more specific.Sorry for miss understanding.

Comment: I suspect that if you're having performance problems loading the whole file into memory at once, there won't be a faster approach than to reload the file each time you need to use it. Line splitting is likely to be faster than the rest of the stuff you're doing!

Comment: @Dragnets NOTE THAT : "_If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference._" From the doumentation on csv module.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly try:

```
import csv
total = 0.0
for row in csv.reader(open("myfile.csv")):
    tall = float(row[0])
    if tall >= 9.956:
        total += tall

print("The sum is: %0.5f" % total)
```

---

More complex version - create calculation classes for processing each row.

```
class Calc(object):
    def process(self,row):
       pass
    def value(self):
        pass

class SumColumn(Calc):
    def __init__(self, column=0,tall=9.956):
        self.column = column
        self.total = 0

    def process(self, row):
        tall = float(row[0])
        if tall >= self.tall:
           self.total += tall

    def value(self):
        return self.total

class ColumnAdder(Calc):
    def __init__(self, col1, col2):
        self.total = 0
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2

    def process(self, row):
        self.total += (row[self.col1] + row[self.col2])

    def value(self):
        return self.total

class ColumnMatcher(Calc):
   def __init__(self, col=4):
      self.matches = 0

   def process(self, row):
      code = row[4]
     import re
     if re.search(r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+', code) is None:
         self.match += 1

   def value(self):
      return self.matches

import csv
col0_sum = SumColumn()
col3_sum = SumColumn(3, 2.45)
col5_6_add = ColumnAdder(5,6)
col4_matches = ColumnMatcher()

for row in csv.reader(open("myfile.csv")):
    col0_sum.process(row)
    col3_sum.process(row)
    col5_6_add.process(row)
    col4_matches.process(row)

print col0_sum.value()
print col3_sum.value()
print col5_6_add.value()
print col4_matches.value()
```

---

This code was typed into SO, which was a tedious affair - so bare with on syntax etc.

For illustration purposes only - not to be taken too literally.

Comment: Using this code would still require for each function to open csv file and split them... What I was thinking that I write one function who does this job and somehow relate them to all my other function, because all my other function is related to the data what is in csv file.

Comment: I'm not sure of your question then, perhaps you could write some code to demonstrate it. If you have ``n``  functions that in effect are calculating based on columns across each row then you it might be best to create classes for each calculation. I'll edit to show what I mean.

Comment: I rewrote the question more specific and add some example

Comment: Your match part could easily be added as a Class that implemented that functionality as I think I've illustrated. It's another Calc that only depends on a row from the file and it can accumulate the result in a similar manner as ColumnAdder.

Comment: I've added an example that mirrors your latest matches regexp. I believe that there's enough there for you to make a good attempt at producing what you want for your other calculations.

Comment: @sotapme It seems to me that ``self.column = column`` is useless, and ``self.tall = tall`` is lacking in the ``__init__`` of **SumColumn**

Comment: @sotapme In **ColumnMatcher**, ``import re`` must not be put in the code block of the **process** function, it would be better to put re as the default argument: ``def process(self, row, re=re)`` .

Comment: @sotapme Your code and mine are similar: for each function a value must be initialized, the evolution of the value is kept in a dictionary in my code and in each function object in your code. But I find that your code need more efforts to be written, for an advantage that doesn't appear very evident for me.

Comment: @sotapme He, commenting your code made me think that all is object in Python, even the functions, so there is no need to define classes as you do, it is overworking. See the edit in my answer. I deleted my former answer.

Comment: @eyquem as I said the code wasn't meant to be taken too literally - I was just trying to demonstrate that if you need to store state across multiple lines of the csv get an object to hold onto it for you. Only the OP really knows what they want to do with it and either solution should work for them. If the calcs were that complicated I throw the data in a SQLite db and work on it from there.

Answer (score 0):

All is object in Python: that means functions too.
So there is no need to define special classes to craft functions as instances of these classes as **sotapme** does, since every function we define is already an object in the sense of 'instance of a class'.

Now, if someone needs to create several functions of the same type, for example each of them adds all the values of a precise CSV file's column, that's right that it's interesting to create these many functions by a repeating process.
At this point, raises the question: using function factory or class ?

Personnaly, I prefer the function factory way because it is less verbose.
I also discovered in the Theran's answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901892/python-factory-functions-compared-to-class) that it's also faster.

In the following code, I use a trick with globals() to give a particular name to each function created by means of a function factory. Some will say it's bad, but I don't know why. If there's another way to do the same , I will be happy to learn it.

In the code, 3 functions are build by a function factory, and I let one defined by plain normal definition (op3).

Python is fantastic!

```
import csv
import re

# To create a CSV file
with open('Data.csv','wb') as csvhandle:
    hw = csv.writer(csvhandle)
    hw.writerows( ((2,10,'%%',3000,'-statusOK-'),
                   (5,3,'##',500,'-modo OOOOKKK-'),
                   (1,60,'**',700,'-- anarada-')) )
del hw

# To visualize the content of the CSV file
with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f:
    print "The CSV file at start :\n  "+\
          '\n  '.join(map(repr,csv.reader(f)))


def run_funcs_on_CSVfile(FUNCS,CSV):
    with open(CSV,'rb') as csvhandle:
        for f in FUNCS:
            # this is necessary for functions not created via
            # via a function factory but via plain definition
            # that defines only the attribute col of the function
            if 'field' not in f.__dict__:
                f.field = f.col - 1
                # columns are numbered 1,2,3,4,...
                # fields are numbered 0,1,2,3,...
        for row in csv.reader(csvhandle):
            for f in FUNCS:
                f(row[f.field])

def SumColumn(name,col,start=0):
    def g(s):
        g.kept += int(s)
    g.kept = start
    g.field = col -1
    g.func_name = name
    globals()[name] = g

def MultColumn(name,col,start=1):
    def g(s):
        g.kept *= int(s)
    g.kept = start
    g.field = col - 1
    g.func_name = name
    globals()[name] = g

def ColumnMatcher(name,col,pat,start = 0):
    RE = re.compile(pat)
    def g(s,regx = RE):
        if regx.search(s):
            g.kept += 1
    g.kept = start
    g.field = col - 1
    g.func_name = name
    globals()[name] = g

SumColumn('op1',1)
MultColumn('op2',2)
ColumnMatcher('op4',5,'O+K')

def op3(s):
    s = int(s)
    if s%2:
        op3.kept += (2*s)
    else:
        op3.kept += s
op3.kept = 0
op3.col = 4


print '\nbefore:\n  ' +\
      '\n  '.join('%s.kept == %d'
                % (f.func_name,  f.kept)
                for f in (op1,op2,op3,op4) )

# The treatment is done here
run_funcs_on_CSVfile((op2,op3,op4,op1),r'Data.csv')
# note that the order of the functions in the tuple
# passed as argument can be any either one or another


print '\nafter:\n  ' +\
      '\n  '.join('%s(column %d) in %s.kept == %d'
                % (f.func_name, f.field+1, f.func_name, f.kept)
                for f in (op1,op2,op3,op4) )
```

.
result
.

```
The CSV file at start :
  ['2', '10', '%%', '3000', '-statusOK-']
  ['5', '3', '##', '500', '-modo OOOOKKK-']
  ['1', '60', '**', '700', '-- anarada-']

before:
  op1.kept == 0
  op2.kept == 1
  op3.kept == 0
  op4.kept == 0

after:
  op1(column 1) in op1.kept == 8
  op2(column 2) in op2.kept == 1800
  op3(column 4) in op3.kept == 4200
  op4(column 5) in op4.kept == 2
```