# Can you make a def method that makes more def methods for Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I've been playing around with tkinter a little and I found that you have to make a def method to use buttons. So I wanted to make 13 buttons because I wanna make a calculator but I really didn't want to make 13 def methods that do very similar things. I tried doing a nested def method (I've never really done that before) but, from what I've tried, it won't work. Am I just doing it wrong or is it just impossible. If it is impossible, is there any other way to mass produce def methods besides a lot of copy and a lot of paste? Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()


window.geometry("500x500")
print("Restarting")
user=""
def oneb():
    global user
    print("1",end="")
    user+="1"
def twob():
    global user
    user+="2"
    print("2",end="")
def threeb():
    global user
    user+="3"
    print("3",end="")
def fourb():
    global user
    user+="4"
    print("4",end="")
def fiveb():
    global user
    user+="5"
    print("5",end="")
def sixb():
    global user
    user+="6"
    print("6",end="")
def sevenb():
    global user
    user+="7"
    print("7",end="")
def eightb():
    global user
    user+="8"
    print("8",end="")
def nineb():
    global user
    user+="9"
    print("9",end="")
def zerob():
    global user
    user+="0"
    print("0",end="")
def plusb():
    global user
    user+="+"
    print("+",end="")
def minusb():
    global user
    print("-",end = "")
def equalb():
    global user
    if "+" in user:
        user=user.partition("+")
        symbol="+"
    elif "-" in user:
        user=user.partition("-")
        symbol="-"
    else:
        print("=",user)
    num1=user[0]
    num2=user[2]
    num1=int(num1)
    num2=int(num2)
    if symbol=="+":
        answer=num1+num2
    else:
        answer=num1-num2
    answer=str(answer)
    print("="+answer)


heightb=5
widthb=10

#I know here I probably should've just made a def method.
one=Button(window, text="1",command=oneb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
one.grid(row=1,column=1)

two=Button(window, text="2",command=twob,height=heightb,width=widthb)
two.grid(row=1,column=2)

three=Button(window, text="3",command=threeb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
three.grid(row=1,column=3)

four=Button(window, text="4",command=fourb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
four.grid(row=2,column=1)

five=Button(window, text="5",command=fiveb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
five.grid(row=2,column=2)

six=Button(window, text="6",command=sixb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
six.grid(row=2,column=3)

seven=Button(window, text="7",command=sevenb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
seven.grid(row=3,column=1)

eight=Button(window, text="8",command=eightb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
eight.grid(row=3,column=2)

nine=Button(window, text="9",command=nineb,height=heightb,width=widthb)
nine.grid(row=3,column=3)

zero=Button(window, text="0",command=zerob,height=heightb,width=widthb)
zero.grid(row=4,column=2)

plus=Button(window, text="+", command=plusb,height=heightb, width=widthb)
plus.grid(row=2,column=4)

minus=Button(window,text="-", command=minusb,height=heightb, width=widthb)
minus.grid(row=1,column=4)

equal=Button(window,text="=", command=equalb,height=heightb, width=widthb)
equal.grid(row=3,column=4)



mainloop()
#button location var.grid(row=x,column=x)
```

Comment: Can you show your code please, and what exactly your trying to accomplish with each button?

Comment: Also, consider using `lambda`s instead of function for your tkinter buttons.

Comment: Have you tried using a method that accepts an additional parameter to identify the button? Then you can keep your common code and execute special code in one def as per the button pressed.

Comment: These are called factory functions. See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901892/python-factory-functions-compared-to-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that returns a function.

For example,

```
def build_button(number):
    def button():
        global user
        user += str(number)
        print(number, end="")
    return button

oneb = build_button(1)
twob = build_button(2)
# ...
```

This should be functionally identical to the [number]b functions you have above.